# Why does this line of generic code work for one entityobject but not for another?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I'm having some troubles using the Generic repository of http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/RepositoryUnit.aspx

There is a line of code in "FetchEntityName" that seems to crash for some entities and not for some other entities, they are all made the same way tough!.

I narrowed it down to this watch expression returning false. (i took 18 as an indexer because that's one of the entities (Group) that doesn't seem to work well)

```
typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)).IsAssignableFrom(this.ObjectContext.GetType().GetProperties()[18].PropertyType)
```

returns false!
left side:

```
typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T))
```

returns in watch:

```
{Name = "IQueryable`1" FullName = "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Domain.Groep, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

right side:

```
this.ObjectContext.GetType().GetProperties()[18].PropertyType
```

returns in watch:

```
{Name = "ObjectSet`1" FullName = "System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[[Contacts.Groep, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

**In english?**

Why aren't ObjectSet and IQueryable assignable to one another for some entities in my EDMX?

Comment: I'm not 100% but I'd imagine it may be to do with GetType() returning say 'Product' but your ObjectContext needing the plural 'Products' for example.

Comment: I'll look into this. I just noticed that this might be some odd namespacing problem, because I can see the Queryable and the ObjectSet have a different Namespace for Group!

Answer (score 1):

I had a second EDMX that contained a groep entity, wich was causing all this trouble.

Simple removing the duplicate entitiy fixed it-;)